Sum Pandas Dataframe rows based on multiple conditions
Scenario: I have a dataframe in which I want to sum rows inside a column, based on values of others columns.
DF Example:
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| SCENARIO |          PRODUCT           |        FLOW         |  2030   |
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Stated   | Natural gas: unabated      | Total energy supply | 147.541 |
| Stated   | Natural gas: with CCUS     | Power sector inputs |   0.018 |
| Stated   | Natural gas: with CCUS     | Total energy supply |   1.147 |
| Stated   | Nuclear                    | Power sector inputs |  36.773 |
| Stated   | Nuclear                    | Total energy supply |  36.773 |
| Stated   | Oil                        | Power sector inputs |   5.162 |
| Stated   | Oil                        | Total energy supply | 194.938 |
| Stated   | Renewables                 | Power sector inputs |  76.612 |
| Stated   | Renewables                 | Total energy supply | 119.979 |
| Stated   | Solar                      | Total energy supply |   22.66 |
| Stated   | Solar PV                   | Power sector inputs |  19.457 |
| Stated   | Total                      | Power sector inputs |   263.2 |
| Stated   | Total                      | Total energy supply | 667.905 |
| Stated   | Traditional use of biomass | Total energy supply |  18.975 |
| Stated   | Wind                       | Power sector inputs |  18.823 |
| Stated   | Wind                       | Total energy supply |  18.823 |
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+

Wanted Result: I want to sum row value of a given column (in this case 2030) based on conditions for other columns. For example: when Scenario = Stated, Flow = Total Energy Supply, I want to sum the values of 2030 where Product is Wind and Solar, so in this case, my result would be a new row in which the value on column 2030 is 22.66 (Solar value) + 18.823 (Wind value), or 41.483. Which would look like:
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| SCENARIO |          PRODUCT           |        FLOW         |  2030   |
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Stated   | Natural gas: unabated      | Total energy supply | 147.541 |
| Stated   | Natural gas: with CCUS     | Power sector inputs |   0.018 |
| Stated   | Natural gas: with CCUS     | Total energy supply |   1.147 |
| Stated   | Nuclear                    | Power sector inputs |  36.773 |
| Stated   | Nuclear                    | Total energy supply |  36.773 |
| Stated   | Oil                        | Power sector inputs |   5.162 |
| Stated   | Oil                        | Total energy supply | 194.938 |
| Stated   | Renewables                 | Power sector inputs |  76.612 |
| Stated   | Renewables                 | Total energy supply | 119.979 |
| Stated   | Solar                      | Total energy supply |   22.66 |
| Stated   | Solar PV                   | Power sector inputs |  19.457 |
| Stated   | Total                      | Power sector inputs |   263.2 |
| Stated   | Total                      | Total energy supply | 667.905 |
| Stated   | Traditional use of biomass | Total energy supply |  18.975 |
| Stated   | Wind                       | Power sector inputs |  18.823 |
| Stated   | Wind                       | Total energy supply |  18.823 |
| Stated   | result_sum                 |                     |  41.483 |
+----------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------+

Issue: While trying different combinations of the df.sum function, I could not get the expected results. If I try to use an operator (e.g. ^ or |) like:
test3 = test3.loc[(test3['SCENARIO'] == 'Stated') & (test3['FLOW'] == 'Total energy supply') & (test3['PRODUCT'] == 'Solar' ^ 'Wind')]

I get an unsupported type error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

If I try to use a series of conditions, I am unsure how to do a multiple selection for the necessary FLOW values:
test3['sigcontr_steps'] = test3.loc[(test3['SCENARIO'] == 'Stated') & (test3['FLOW'] == 'Total energy supply') & 
                                    (test3['PRODUCT'] == 'Solar') & (test3['PRODUCT'] == 'Wind'),[2022]].sum(axis=0)

This does not work because of the two values for PRODUCT at the same time.
Question: What is the correct way to perform this operation?


If you have multiple conditions for a column, you can use .isin.
To get the sum your can group on 'SCENARIO' and aggregate using sum.
Finally, you can use concat to join the original dataframe and the sum.

df = test3.loc[
    (test3["SCENARIO"] == "Stated")
    & (test3["FLOW"] == "Total energy supply")
    & (test3["PRODUCT"].isin(["Solar", "Wind"]))
]

df = df.groupby("SCENARIO", as_index=False).sum()
df["PRODUCT"] = "result_sum"
df["FLOW"] = ""

out = pd.concat([test3, df])

   SCENARIO                     PRODUCT                 FLOW     2030
0    Stated       Natural gas: unabated  Total energy supply  147.541
1    Stated      Natural gas: with CCUS  Power sector inputs    0.018
2    Stated      Natural gas: with CCUS  Total energy supply    1.147
3    Stated                     Nuclear  Power sector inputs   36.773
4    Stated                     Nuclear  Total energy supply   36.773
5    Stated                         Oil  Power sector inputs    5.162
6    Stated                         Oil  Total energy supply  194.938
7    Stated                  Renewables  Power sector inputs   76.612
8    Stated                  Renewables  Total energy supply  119.979
9    Stated                       Solar  Total energy supply   22.660
10   Stated                    Solar PV  Power sector inputs   19.457
11   Stated                       Total  Power sector inputs  263.200
12   Stated                       Total  Total energy supply  667.905
13   Stated  Traditional use of biomass  Total energy supply   18.975
14   Stated                        Wind  Power sector inputs   18.823
15   Stated                        Wind  Total energy supply   18.823
0    Stated                  result_sum                        41.483

